# How can I merge two tabs in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I am unable to find the way how can i merge these two tabs in excel when i go to customize ribbon I only able to see "scraping" but unable to find "SCRAPING TOOLS"  what is the reason? attached is the screenshot. [image: excel image]

Comment: Flip the dropdown to all tabs?

Comment: there are two different buttons on two different tabs ( " scraping " and " scraping tool") i want to merge both in one single tab

Comment: This appears to be a custom Add-in.  Do you have access to the code?

Comment: yes, but I am newbie so i am not able to understand the code well

Comment: Given that you have access to the code, you should look into **Custom UI** which can be found here https://bettersolutions.com/vba/ribbon/custom-ui-editor.htm